# Modules inside Module in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter hmvc architecture,

I want to implement modules inside main project.

Is there any possible way to implement Structure like this.

```
Codeigniter root
    application
      modules
        admin
          modules
            admin1
            admin2
            admin3
        client
           modules
             client1
             client2
```

Comment: In your `config.php` look like where you setup the `$config['modules_locations'] = array( APPPATH.'module/' => '../module/', );`

Comment: You can see this also: https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Comment: I already implement that solution but id does not help me.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can use this :

```
Codeigniter root
    application
      modules
        admin
          controllers
            admin
            admin1
            admin2
        client
           controllers
             client
             client1
             client2
```

And for acces at *client2*, the url is *yourdomain.com/client/client2*

Comment: i want seperate module for all submodules.